# What does normalizing along any axis mean in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have understood what normalizing using  `tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=0)` and `tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)` mean mathematically -> If our columns are features and rows are data samples, using `axis=0` means normalizing every feature w.r.t the sum of that feature across all samples. 
Now when we have an image of say dimension 28*28, what does the normalizing axis depend on ? Each image is a data sample, so I am confused on what axis to normalize the pixel values corresponding to a single image. In almost every tutorial and example, `axis=1` is taken and the normalization is done on all the images together.

In addition to the mathematical operation, I would love to understand the reasoning behind the choice of axis too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Channel-wise normalization** can mess up the visual representation of an image and that is always harder to conduct sanity check.

**Question 1:**  Now when we have an image of say dimension 28*28, what does the normalizing axis depend on?

If you have **28*28*1** (assuming 1 channel), you can normalize this Image based on its **arrangement** in the dataset. Typically value used here is `1`, because the Images are commonly **Stacked rather than Concatenated**.

```
[Image 0]     Compared to [Image 0][Image 1][Image 2][Image ...]
[Image 1]
[Image 2]
[Image ...]
```

Meaning you can reference it like this:

```
Image[0] = (28*28*1) // 28*28 is the number of Columns per Row (Image)
Image[1] = (28*28*1)
```

**Question 2:**  Each image is a data sample, so I am confused on what axis to normalize the pixel values corresponding to a single image. In almost every tutorial and example, axis=1 is taken and the normalization is done on all the images together.

Normalizing Data means 2 things:

1. Putting the data on the **same scale** (Scaling) that improves convergence speed and accuracy.

```
Scaling is commonly 0 to 1, -1 to 1, and -1 to 1 with 0 mean.
```

2. **Balancing** the data around a point (Centering) that fights exploding and vanishing gradients, and also increasing convergence and accuracy.

As I indicated in the answer in Question 1, the value axis = 1 is due to the images being stacked.

```
Image[0][28*28_pixels]
Image[1][28*28_pixels]
Image[...][28*28_pixels]
```

Hence, when you normalize in `axis = 1  (columns)` you could get the **right scale** considering all the values in the pixel location `pixel 1 is compared to pixel 1 of all the images`, which is done on the **WHOLE dataset** so the normalization is **balanced** throughout the data **to a certain point**.